# TextRact Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request) + IAM Keys not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-textract

I have pushed my textract code on staging server, and now I am receiving an error.

It is working on a development system. I can't understand why it is happening.

I am using dotnet core 3.0

I am following code sample provided here.  [https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-code-samples/tree/master/src-csharp]

I have a doubt regarding IAM credentials. For this, I installed AWS SDK tools for Windows and AWS CLI on staging server and, after that, ran commands (mentioned here  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration] ) using Command prompt for configuring. I thought it (IAM) might be getting saved into the environment. But no success.

Code which uploads a file on S3 bucket is uploading it, but while making a request to Textract service, it is crashing.

**System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)**

I can't understand what's the issue.
On development, it is working.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found solution. It was very weird issue, never thought it will come.

**First thing**

Message thrown by API was not clear. So we hosted it on some other server which had upgraded windows OS. There we came to know it is related to keys which was generated during creation of IAM user.

**Second thing**

Although we got cleared that our application (Amazon's Textract dll) is not able to read keys which we configured from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) .

When we configure through CLI,  it creates two files for saving credentials and read it from here. Refer below screen shot.

[image]

It was there but still application was not able to locate it on staging server. After searching for 4-5 days talking to the AWS support nothing happened.

Finally we dived into IIS made few changes and came to know it is happening at IIS. In IIS there is setting in **Appool of instance it was Load User Profile.**. By default it come as false but when we turned as true it crated a user like we have user for system log-in.
Refer below screen shots for changing this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It creates user like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps some one